# DataTables warning - Invalid JSON response while integrating sort by filter

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatable, datatables

I use jQuery DataTables and get this warning message:

> DataTables warning  - Invalid JSON response

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataTable = $('#users_table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        responsive: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        oLanguage: {
            oPaginate: {
                sFirst: "<<",
                sPrevious: "<",
                sNext: ">",
                sLast: ">>"
            }
        },
        "order": [],           
        "ajax": {
            url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/users/fetch_user'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: function (d) {
                d.type = $(".type_filter:checked").val();
            }
        }
    });

    $(".type_filter").click(function () {
        dataTable.draw();
    });
 });
```

When apply Filter:-

> DataTables warning: table id=users_table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Please help

Comment: ajax `data` property is used to send data to your server. `data` can only be an Plain Object, String, or Array. I think you seek `success`. The `success` property takes a function that receives data from your Server.

Comment: @PHPglue looks like you can use a function now to manipulate the data first.

Comment: it looks like the main problem is the data you're getting back from `admin/users/fetch_user`. can you see it through dev tools? it appears to be invalid somehow.